# How do I compare select all values larger than their average?

Tags: prometheus

Let's say I have the following data

```
my_metric{instance="0"} = 1
my_metric{instance="1"} = 2
my_metric{instance="2"} = 3
```

I'm interested in querying all metrics that are larger than the average of them all. `my_metric > avg(my_metric)` doesn't seem to work. My guess is that it's because `avg(my_metric)` isn't a scalar, but a 1-element vector. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  metric 
> ignoring (instance) group_left  
  avg without(instance)(metric)
```

See 
https://www.robustperception.io/using-group_left-to-calculate-label-proportions/