# PromQL: Find below-average vector elements

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a Prometheus vector metric (`etcd_network_client_grpc_received_bytes_total`) with a label (`instance`). The metric has a different value for each of a bunch of label values (i.e. one value per `instance`). I want to find all `instance`s for which the value is smaller than 70% of the average of all instances.

For example, if the vector had the following values:

```
etcd_network_client_grpc_received_bytes_total{instance="192.168.0.18:2399"} 19021275139
etcd_network_client_grpc_received_bytes_total{instance="192.168.0.22:2399"} 390020
etcd_network_client_grpc_received_bytes_total{instance="192.168.0.30:2399"} 19021275254
etcd_network_client_grpc_received_bytes_total{instance="192.168.0.48:2399"} 38992
etcd_network_client_grpc_received_bytes_total{instance="192.168.0.49:2399"} 1992
```

...then the query should return the 2nd, 4th and 5th element.

What doesn't work:

```
etcd_network_client_grpc_received_bytes_total < (0.7 * avg (etcd_network_client_grpc_received_bytes_total))
```

(I guess because the whole thing is evaluated for each label value)

Is this possible?

(I should actually be comparing rates, not totals, but let's keep it simple for now)

Comment: Btw. the one thing I thought might work would be a recording rule for the average, but that seems excessive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
etcd_network_client_grpc_received_bytes_total
< ignoring(instance) group_left
0.7 * avg without(instance)(etcd_network_client_grpc_received_bytes_total)
```

See [How do I compare select all values larger than their average?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397890/how-do-i-compare-select-all-values-larger-than-their-average)