# Is it possible to calculate Ranks of metrics?

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics

###### Am I missing something or is there no function in promql to calculate either one of the following:

- the **Rank** of a metric among previous observations of that same metric.
- the **Percent Rank** of a metric among all previous observations of that same metric.
- Something like the **inverse** of `quantile_over_time()`

A roundabout way might be to:

1. Count how many observations are smaller than the observation at each timestamp.
2. Divide result from 1. by total number of observations.

However that still seems beyond my skill so I am looking for some direction on which way I should pursue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need [share_le_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#share_le_over_time) function from VictoriaMetrics (I work on this Prometheus-like system). For example, the following query returns the share of raw samples during the last hour per each series with name `m`, which don't exceed 42:

```
share_le_over_time(m[1h], 42)
```

The returned share is in the range `0 .. 1`, where `0` means 0%, while `1` means 100%.

Additionally, you may look at [histogram_share](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_share) function - it returns the share of samples from histogram buckets, which don't exceed the given threshold. I.e. it is an inverse of `histogram_quantile` function.

Comment: Thanks! very useful function. I do like how VictoriaMetrics offers all these extra functions. For my use case they do not accept a function for argument#2, something like `share_le_over_time(m[1h], last_over_time(m[1h]))` so I've been trying to work out a solution based on this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43402552/5907933) but unsuccessfully so far. I got to find a way to write a query that uses the single last value of a metric and compare it to a whole vector of previous values of that same metric. But I'm now learning all this stuff so very open to any other suggestions if you have.

Comment: The `share_le_over_time()` function expects a single time series as the `le` param. The `last_over_time(...)` in your case returns multiple time series. The workaround is to add more specific filters to `m` series selector inside `last_over_time()`, so it returns a single time series. Another workaround is to wrap `last_over_time()` into aggregate function, which returns a single series. For example, `avg(last_over_time(m[1h]))`